# math syntax doesn't work when using siunitx syntax for alignment on decimal point in tables

Tags: tables, math-mode, siunitx

I have the following problem: Math syntax doesn't work for the labels in the second row in my table for h=1, h=3, h=6. How can i fix it?

Here is my code for it. Thank you

Comment: Could you please make your code compilable? (See [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)) How is `\twoS` defined?

Comment: `\newcommand*{\oneS}{\SuperScriptSameStyle{*}}
\newcommand*{\twoS}{\SuperScriptSameStyle{**}}
\newcommand*{\threeS}{\SuperScriptSameStyle{*{*}*}}`

Comment: How/Where is `\SuperScriptSameStyle` defined?

Comment: `\newcommand*{\SuperScriptSameStyle}[1]{%
  \ensuremath{%
    \mathchoice
      {{}^{\displaystyle #1}}%
      {{}^{\textstyle #1}}%
      {{}^{\scriptstyle #1}}%
      {{}^{\scriptscriptstyle #1}}%
  }%
}`

Comment: Please edit your question to include this additional information. Please also inclue teh documentclass as well as the relevant packages in order to make your code compilable without the need to guess some settings.

Answer (score 1):

Here is part of your table. I have used `tabularx` for automated line breaks in the last column, `threeparttablex` for the formatting of the tablenotes, added some `sisetup` options nd removed unnecessary `\multicolumn` commands as well as empty rows. Adapting the rest of the table is now up to you.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{booktabs}\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\newcommand*{\SuperScriptSameStyle}[1]{% 
\ensuremath{% 
\mathchoice {{}^{\displaystyle #1}}% 
{{}^{\textstyle #1}}% 
{{}^{\scriptstyle #1}}% 
{{}^{\scriptscriptstyle #1}}%
 }% 
 } 
\newcommand*{\oneS}{\SuperScriptSameStyle{*}} 
\newcommand*{\twoS}{\SuperScriptSameStyle{**}} 
\newcommand*{\threeS}{\SuperScriptSameStyle{*{*}*}}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[flushleft, para, referable]{threeparttablex}
\setTableNoteFont{\itshape}
\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}[htbp]
\begin{threeparttable}
\centering
\sisetup{
    table-align-text-pre     = false,
    table-align-text-post    = false,
    input-open-uncertainty   = ,
    input-close-uncertainty  = ,
    table-space-text-post    = \threeS,
    table-space-text-pre     = {(},
    parse-numbers = false,
}


\caption{RMSFE for $h=1, h=3$ and $h=6$ Step-Ahead Forecasts of $\Delta UR_{t}$}
 \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ll*{3}{S[table-format=2.4]}X}
 \toprule
       &       & \multicolumn{3}{c}{RMSFE} &  \\
\cmidrule{3-5}  
       &       & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Forecast Horizon} &  \\
 Variable & Model & {$h=1$}   &  {$h=3$}   & {$h=6$}   &  Details \\
 \midrule
 $\Delta UR_{t}$ & AR$(BIC)$ & 0.1750 & 0.1996 & 0.2346 &  $h$-step ahead forecasts with AR model in $\Delta UR_{t}$, lags determined by $BIC$ \\
       &       &       &       &       &  \\ \addlinespace
 $\Delta UR_{t}$, $\Delta G1_{t}$ & VAR$(BIC)$ & 0.1613\oneS & 0.1606\oneS & 0.1816\twoS &  \multirow[t]{2}{=}{$\Delta UR_{t}$ $h$-step-ahead forecasts with VAR model in $\Delta UR_{t}$ and $\Delta G1_{t}$, lags determined by $BIC$} \\
       &       & [1.8387] & [1.8416] & [2.0047] &   \\

 \bottomrule
 \end{tabularx}%
 \begin{tablenotes}
 \note Critical values of the DM test: $10\% = 1.64, 5\% =1.96$ and $1\% = 2.34$. \newline DM test statistics are given in the brackets, asteriks indicate significance at: \oneS 10\%, \twoS 5\% and \threeS 1\%
 \end{tablenotes}
 \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}%
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```